# XSLT 1.0 DISTINCT For-each loop

Tags: sql, xml, if-statement, xslt

I need some help with a problem in my XSLT code
regarding making for-each loop on distinct values in XSLT 1.0
I will add the XML example and the full XSLT

XML:

```
  <DATACOLLECTION>
<DATA>
    <LINES>
      <LINE>
        <LOADS>
          <LOAD>
            <CONTAINER>
              <ContaineId>KCT001232508</ContaineId>
            </CONTAINER>
          </LOAD>
        </LOADS>
      </LINE>
      <LINE>
        <LOADS>
          <LOAD>
            <CONTAINER>
              <ContaineId>KCT00666666</ContaineId>
            </CONTAINER>
          </LOAD>
        </LOADS>
      </LINE>
      <LINE>
        <LOADS>
          <LOAD>
            <CONTAINER>
              <ContaineId>KCT001232508</ContaineId>
            </CONTAINER>
          </LOAD>
        </LOADS>
      </LINE>
    </LINES>
</DATA>
</DATACOLLECTION>
```

My completed XSLT code:

```
</msxml:script>


    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name ="ServerDateFormat" select ="'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'"/>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="DATACOLLECTION/DATA">
     <PACKAGEDETAILES>
     <xsl:for-each select="LINES/LINE/LOADS/LOAD/CONTAINER">
     <xsl:variable name="CONTAINER"><xsl:value-of select="ContainerId"/></xsl:variable>
     <PACKAGEDETAILE>
        <NetWeight><xsl:value-of select="cd:GetDataFromDB('WEIGHT', 'vContainerContent', concat( 'ORDERID = ', cd:FormatValue($ORDERID), 'AND CONTAINER = ' , cd:FormatValue($CONTAINER)))"/></NetWeight>
        <GrossWeight></GrossWeight>
        <WeightUnit></WeightUnit>
        <Length><xsl:value-of select="cd:GetDataFromDB('LENGTH', 'vContainerContent', concat( 'ORDERID = ', cd:FormatValue($ORDERID), 'AND CONTAINER = ' , cd:FormatValue($CONTAINER)))"/></Length>
        <Width><xsl:value-of select="cd:GetDataFromDB('WIDTH', 'vContainerContent', concat( 'ORDERID = ', cd:FormatValue($ORDERID), 'AND CONTAINER = ' , cd:FormatValue($CONTAINER)))"/></Width>
        <Height><xsl:value-of select="cd:GetDataFromDB('HEIGHT', 'vContainerContent', concat( 'ORDERID = ', cd:FormatValue($ORDERID), 'AND CONTAINER = ' , cd:FormatValue($CONTAINER)))"/></Height>
        <SizeUnit></SizeUnit>
        <Volume></Volume>
        <VolumeUnit></VolumeUnit>
     </PACKAGEDETAILE>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </PACKAGEDETAILES>
    </PackingList>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to show tag:

```
<PACKAGEDETAILE></PACKAGEDETAILE>
```

only for distinct ContainerId values, thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50841290/3710053

Comment: didn't understand how to implant it in my case

Comment: Please share the complete xslt and adjust the expected outcome to 100%

Comment: The preferred method to extract distinct values in XSLT 1.0 is by Muenchian grouping. Read about here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html and come back if you have a specific problem with the implementation. Note that there are a great many examples of Muenchian grouping on SO.